# Create Intervals of weeks in UILocalNotification along with cycle

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am making app which is using UILocalNotification. I want to know how to make gaps in UILocalNotification i.e. how could I schedule alarm for 4 weeks(repeat daily or once in every other day) and off for 1 week and again on for 4 weeks and off for 1 weeks and so on. This is just a single case. These gaps are dynamic and are decided at runtime.

Comment: still waiting for an answer......its one week now

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `repeatInterval` since you want a special repetition scheme. I think you have to schedule a local notification for each day you want to have one:

- 28 notifications for each day of the first 4 weeks,
- 28 notifications for each day of the second period of 4 weeks,
- and so on...

Some code that may help:

```
/**
  This method will schedule 28 notifications, each 24 hours exactly for 4 weeks,
  starting from dayOne (first notification will be at dayOne, the second one
  at dayOne + 24 hours..., so be sure to choose the hour you want by setting
  dayOne correctly.
 */
- (void)scheduleLocalNotificationsEachDayFor4WeeksStartingFrom:(NSDate *)dayOne {

  // Schedule notifications for each day during 4 weeks starting at dayOne
  NSMutableArray *notifications = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    [notifications addObject:notificationForDay(dayOne, i)];
  }
  for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
  }
}

UILocalNotification *notificationInSomeDays(NSDate *referenceDate, NSUInteger some) {
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];

  // Notification timing
  NSUInteger days = 60*60*24; // number of seconds in a day
  notification.fireDate = [referenceDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:some * days];
  notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; // use local time zone if your reference date is a local one, or choose the appropriate time zone

  // define your notification content...

  return notification;
}
```

You can use the `scheduleLocalNotificationsEachDayFor4WeeksStartingFrom:` method to schedule the 28 notifications you need for each period of 4 weeks. So you can now just run this as often as needed by calling it with the first day of each period of 4 weeks you want notifications to be started.

When you're app is started, you should clean all current local notifications and reschedule them to match your requirements. In particular, you'll have to adjust if the app is started during a 4 weeks period where notifications should be run. In this case you will have to adjust the proposed `scheduleLocalNotificationsEachDayFor4WeeksStartingFrom` method to reduce the number of scheduled notifications...

Answer (score 0):

She means to say that these gaos are dynamic....so if she set 28 notification for first 4 week and 28 notification for second period and so on....then this will cross 64 local notification per app.......also these gaps are dynamic means it can be anything suppose 12 weeks on / 1 week off.....then by ur method she has to set 84 notification for a single medicine(crosses limit) and their are surely more than one medicine of these kind...

Comment: I can see the issue, which wasn't explained in the question. I see no solution, except for considering the user has to start the app sometimes so that the appropriate notifications can be setup within the limit (which I wasn't aware of). Or use push notifications. By the way, I think you should have written a comment on my answer, instead of writing a comment as an answer.